# rmadmin not connecting in hadoop yarn (label based scheduling)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, resourcemanager

I am giving labels to hadoop yarn cluster

I have set my IP of all nodes correctly and it's working properly for all other applications, but why this is happening for rmadmin only ?

Command:

```
yarn rmadmin -replaceLabelsOnNode "pooja=fast kalpesh=slow"
```

i am getting errors like .......

```
16/03/15 17:47:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8033. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 17:47:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8033. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 17:47:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8033. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 17:47:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8033. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 17:48:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8033. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

My yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
  <value>ankit21:8032</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>ankit21:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
  <value>ankit21:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
      <name>yarn.node-labels.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>node.labels.monitor.interval </name>
   <value>15000</value>
   <description> Interval for checking the labels file for updates (default is 120000 ms)
   </description>
 </property>
<property>
      <name>node.labels.file</name>
      <value>/nodes_labels_new</value>
 </property>
<property>
      <name>yarn.node-labels.fs-store.root-dir</name>
      <value>hdfs://ankit21/</value>
 </property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.rmadmin.address</name>
  <value>ankit21:8033</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i did is ..

removed this from yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
      <name>yarn.node-labels.fs-store.root-dir</name>
      <value>hdfs://ankit21/</value>
 </property>
```

I think it was conflicting..